# MVC4 minified jQuery bundle

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In the BundleConfig.cs I would like to make the following:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

use the minified version instead. I tried:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js"));
```

but the jquery file was no longer included in my site. I am self hosting the minified version and it is present on the server.

Comment: Is it included in your project?  i.e. right click on it in Visual Studio and click "include in project."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

min versions of scripts are ignored while in debug mode due to the BundleCollection.IgnoreList. It can be modified to clear out the -min.js and other files, if needed.

[Advanced options of Bundling and minfication](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2012/09/30/hidden-options-of-asp-net-bundling-and-minification.aspx)

and while the suggestion of turning of debug in the web.config will work, you lose debug ability entirely for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the top code, but turn debug off in the web.config. It will then use the minified version